# Meaning of these terms - Simulation of vector control (FOC) of induction motor?

Tags: simulation, motor-controller, induction-motor

I'm having hard time doing simulation of vector control for 3 phase asynchronous machine. I was studying MATLAB - Simulink simulations available already on MathWorks site but I couldn't understand that what certain terms mean.

1. `1e-3` was added in denominator for following two equations. [image][image]

As you can see the equations written below model by author himself gives no clue as why 1e-3 is there. And this is not the only one simulation which has this term here. Even Mathwork's site has this term as can be seen from [this page.](https://in.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ug/building-your-own-drive.html)
But I couldn't find any documentation as from where does it comes. Is it because they want to ensure there won't be division by 0? But then isn't 1e-3 quite larger term? This was wild guess ...

2. The last block in previous figure (K*Ts/(z-1)) shows discrete time integrator right? But what is the difference between that integrator and one shown below (it is PI Torque controller) and what is its significance? Note that this is also part of the same page linked above.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possibly a very small value is added to avoid singularity if denominator would be zero?

Comment: Yes, I too thought the same. Do you have any idea about that discrete integrator?

Comment: It integrates the speed to get the angle. "integ(WR+WM)"

Comment: Hmm are you sure that is being performed in this block? Isn't it just PI torque controller which generates torque command based on speed error.

Comment: No, for sure. PI controller is composed by an integrator and gain, two paralell branches. What you actaually have is integrator, only.

Comment: Oh now I realize that you were talking about first pic @MarkoBuršič , yes I do understand that but what does (z+1)/(z-1)2 means in second pic? Can you please explain?

Comment: It's a trapezoidal rule intergrator, IMO. You'll find explanation in Tustin method of discretization, aka Bilinear transform.

Comment: Yes, I found my answer here : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/51990/37729